# Is getc a macro or a function?

Tags: c, linux, unix, macros

I tried to find the difference between `getc` and `fgetc`. At that time I saw a statement like:

> The difference between getc and fgetc is that getc can be implemented as a macro, whereas fgetc cannot be implemented as a macro.

So, is `getc` really a function or it is a macro? If it is macro, it calls some other function. So, is `getc` implemented in C or not?

Comment: That depends on your C library, really. `getc()` *may* be implemented as a macro... or it may not, and that is subject to change in the future.

Comment: So, It is not a unique function like fgetc, fgets. Is it write?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The difference between getc and fgetc is that getc can be implemented as a macro, whereas fgetc cannot be implemented as a macro.

That's incorrect.

With a few exceptions, *any* C standard library function may additionally be implemented as a macro, but there are some restrictions on how that macro can be written (so that the macro can still be used as if it were a function).

Quoting [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) section 7.1.4:

> Any function declared in a header may be additionally implemented as a
>   function-like macro defined in the header, [...] Any invocation of a
>   library function that is implemented as a macro shall expand to code
>   that evaluates each of its arguments exactly once, fully protected by
>   parentheses where necessary, so it is generally safe to use arbitrary
>   expressions as arguments.

What's special about `getc` is that one of those restrictions may be relaxed (7.21.7.5):

> The **`getc`** function is equivalent to **`fgetc`**, except that if
>   it is implemented as a macro, it may evaluate **`stream`** more than
>   once, so the argument should never be an expression with side effects.

The declarations of `fgetc` and `getc` are:

```
int fgetc(FILE *stream);
int getc(FILE *stream);
```

The `stream` argument (for example, in a call like `fgetc(stdin)` or `getc(file)` is almost always an expression without side effects, but the rules still forbid defining `fgetc` as a macro that evaluates its argument more than once, just in case a programmer writes something like `fgetc(file_list[i++])`. The rule is relaxed for `getc` so that it can be defined as a macro (which can be significantly more efficient in some cases), while potentially breaking something like `getc(file_list[i++])`.

In the case of `fgetc`, there probably wouldn't be much advantage in implementing it as a macro rather than just as a function. The point is that the standard explicitly permits it.

> So, is `getc` implemented in C or not?

Maybe.  There's no requirement for *any* C library function to be implemented in C. Some functions might be implemented in assembler, or in any other language -- or they might be compiler intrinsics. Usually most or all C standard library functions *are* implemented in C, but the standard only specifies how they work, not how they're written.

Answer (score 1):

`getc` is a function as stated in C99 standard section 7.21.7.5 and may or may not be implemented as a macro:

> The `getc` function is equivalent to `fgetc`, except that if it is implemented as a macro, it may evaluate `stream` more than once, so the argument should never be an expression with side effects.

It does not work correctly with an argument that has side effects. For example --

```
int c = getc(*fpp++);
```

Comment: So, It depends up on the version of C

Comment: @mohan: No, it doesn't depend on the version of C. The standard's description of `fgetc` and `getc` is essentially the same in C90, C99, and C11.

Comment: @mohan  No it wont be dependent on versions of C.

Comment: `fgetc`, *can* be implemented as a macro. There are just more restrictions on how that macro can be written. See my answer for details.

Comment: @KeithThompson `fgetc` can be implementated as macro ?

Comment: @ameyCU: Any standard C library function can be implemented as a macro. There's probably not much reason to do so in the case of `fgetc`, but it's allowed. see my answer.